# Extracting twitter user associated with tweet using Tweepy

Tags: python

I've got code to extract some twitter data using a delayed loop.  I would like to add the associated user for each tweet to my data collection but I'm having a lot of difficulty getting this to work...

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob
import csv
import time

count = 0
num = 0

numTimesToRepeat = 3

for i in range(numTimesToRepeat):
    if i>0:
        num = num + 1

        print("")
        print(num)
        print("")       

        print("NEW SEARCH BEGINS HERE " + str(num))

        consumer_key = '******'
        consumer_secret = '******'

        access_token = '******'
        access_token_secret = '******'

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

        api = tweepy.API(auth)


        public_tweets_list = api.search('"meaningful work"', count=200)


        fieldnames = ['count', 'Tweet', 'polarity_analysis', 'tweettime', 'rating']#, 'user']


        file_name = str("tweet_data" + str(num) + ".csv")

        writer = csv.DictWriter(open(file_name, "w"), fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()



        for tweet in public_tweets_list:
            analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
            api.get_user('screen_name')#THIS LINE NOT WORKING
            print(api.get_user('screen_name'))#THIS LINE NOT WORKING


            if analysis.sentiment.polarity < -.7:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Very Negative",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })

            elif analysis.sentiment.polarity < -.3:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Moderately Negative",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })

            elif analysis.sentiment.polarity < 0:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Slightlyly Negative",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })


            elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Neutral",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })

            elif analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Slightlyly Positive",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })

            elif analysis.sentiment.polarity > .3:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Moderately Positive",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })

            elif analysis.sentiment.polarity > .7:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Moderately Positive",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })

            else:
                print("")
                print(tweet.text)
                print(tweet.created_at)
                count = count + 1
                print(count)
                writer.writerow({
                    "count": str(count),
                    "Tweet": str(tweet.text),
                    "polarity_analysis": "Error",
                    "tweettime": str(tweet.created_at),
                    "rating": analysis.sentiment,
                    "user": str(tweet.text) #THIS LINE NOT WORKING

                })
        time.sleep(60) # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds).
```

The result I get is

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SentimentAnalysis.py", line 145, in <module>
    api.get_user('screen_name')#THIS LINE NOT WORKING
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 63, 'message': 'User has been suspended.'}]`

Answer (score 0):

**tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 63, 'message': 'User has been suspended.'}]**

Twitter does get to suspend accounts for certain reasons known to them. Therefore, the error returned shows you can't proceed. This is because the account does not exist.

Option 1: Try out another user.

Option 2: Keep checking till the account is restored (nobody knows when this would happen).

Comment: I should clarify, this code does not use any specific user's account info, it searches for tweets with the "public_tweets_list = api.search('"meaningful work"', count=200)" code - in this case searching for tweets under the term "meaningful work").  I have a feeling that I'm getting this error because no user is specified in my search terms (even though the system is pulling 200 tweets from each search)

Comment: You could try specifying a user then.